# Running mysqld with root privilege

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

As we know running mysql with root privilege is not recommended which leads to privilege escalation using UDF's.
I'm trying to setup a machine to demonstrate this and I wanted to run mysqld as root user.

[MySQL UDF exploitation](https://redteamnation.com/mysql-user-defined-functions/) for more info.

Im running ubuntu 21.04 and with mysql-server

mysql version:

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

*Changing the file ownership to root*

```
chown -R root /var/lib/mysql
```

*/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf*

```
[mysqld]
user        = root
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
```

I am getting error

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-05-25 08:29:56 PDT; 23s ago
    Process: 2413 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2421 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2421 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Error: 13 (Permission denied)
```

However, If I change the file permissions of */var/lib/mysql* back to *mysql* user the service starts.
Please let me know the solution how I can run it as root.
If I am doing anything wrong please suggest clear steps.

Ref:

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqld` service runs as the `mysql` user by default as is specified in the service file. There is no reason to run it as root as doing so wouldn't provide anything that isn't there with it running as the `mysql` user. PostgreSQL and MongoDB also run as their respective users and not as root.

There's no reason to fix what isn't broken.

Comment: He wants to test privilege escalation to show to his younger teammates why it's not safe to run mysql as root.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici He can add that to the question or better yet, direct them to resources that explain what can go wrong.

Comment: I felt it would be better to show a practical demo and I'm stumbled upon here.